# Run PowerShell script in Vagrant

Tags: powershell, vagrant

I use this command to run script in Vagrant via PowerShell

```
vagrant.exe powershell -c "SchTasks /Create /TN 'InstallTask' /SC ONCE /ST 23:59 /IT /RL HIGHEST /TR 'powershell -Command c:/vagrant/I_O.ps1' /F | Out-Host; SchTasks /Run /TN 'InstallTask' | Out-Host;"
```

But it works only if I start it manually from PowerShell ISE and as a separate command.

I want to use it inside this script block

```
# Run Vagrant

vagrant up

# Run PowerShell in Vagrant

vagrant.exe powershell -c "Set-Location C:\vagrant"

#Set policy to Unrestricted

vagrant.exe powershell -c "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force"

# Install Chocolatey

 vagrant.exe powershell -c "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"

# Turn off confirmation in Chocolatey

vagrant.exe powershell -c "chocolatey feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation"

# Install .net 3.5

vagrant.exe powershell -c "choco install dotnet3.5 -force"

# Run O installation script

vagrant.exe powershell -c "SchTasks /Create /TN 'InstallTask' /SC ONCE /ST 23:59 /IT /RL HIGHEST /TR 'powershell -Command c:/vagrant/I_O.ps1' /F | Out-Host; SchTasks /Run /TN 'InstallTask' | Out-Host;"
```

Comment: What errors are you getting. That might give us a clue what's going wrong with the statement.

Comment: No errors in PowerShell ISE, "executed succesfully wi
th output code 0."

Comment: how about in vagrant? does it throw errors there?